# git fsck fails with the same error for 4 different repositories

Tags: git

I'm running `git fsck` command on some repositories, and for 4 of them I got the same error:

```
error in tree b2b510c83ea553c587ebe5bc160e92cb7888393a: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree b3969ac6fe6b6359d48006e6a4cf3ffd5a4350a3: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 5a7445940626358083a782ba5c81f956c7f82ac5: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
```

any idea how to fix it? what does it mean that it appears exactly the same for all?

Comment: Have you tried `git fsck --full`?

Comment: same error as `git fsck`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git stores the contents of a directory in a tree object.  In general, tree objects are supposed to be in sorted filename order by byte value.

This message means that those particular tree objects contain a duplicate entry, which isn't supposed to be the case.  Whatever tool you're using to create these objects has created corrupt ones, and Git is now complaining.

To fix it, you should first stop using whatever tool created these problems so you don't make it worse.  Then, you can run `git gc --prune=now` to delete unused objects immediately.  You can then run `git fsck` to see if the commits are gone; if they're not in the history, they'll have been deleted.

If this doesn't work, then you can rewrite the repository by creating a new repository and running something like the following:

```
git fast-export --all | (cd /empty/repository && git fast-import)
```

This will necessarily rewrite some of your object IDs, but Git will not import the duplicate values when it writes the new repository.

Comment: Tnx! I will try it and update

Comment: I ran the command `git gc --prune=now` and got: `Enumerating objects: 48656, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Total 18 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
Computing commit graph generation numbers: 100% (9422/9422), done.` afterward, I ran again `git fsck` but got the same errors as earlier

Comment: BTW, when running `git ls -tree` on each one of the trees, I see what is duplicate: `040000 tree bedd93cf41a5d3ed9b19a2062cd7f49e930d4227    resources
040000 tree bedd93cf41a5d3ed9b19a2062cd7f49e930d4227    resources`

Comment: one more comment, I saw in one of the threads something similar to your command: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: Okay, then in that case, you'll need to use the `git fast-export` technique.  That will rewrite your history, but you'll need to do that to fix it.

Comment: I didn't understand the syntax. how do I rewrite the problematic repository to the new one?

Comment: You need to create a new repository in another directory, say, `../destination`, and then run `git fast-export --all | (cd ../destination && git fast-import)` at a shell prompt.

Comment: I should run the command from the problematic repository path, right?

Comment: Yes, in the problematic repository.

Comment: I ran it and saw a new folder was created in the repository named `.git`, and then `git fsck `passed, however, I see `objects` folder is missing almost all the subdirectories (it contains only `info` and `pack`). BTW, when I ran the command I got: `-ksh: export: --all: unknown option`

Comment: `git fast-import` writes a pack file, so there are no loose objects.  In addition, it sounds like you either put an extra space in `git fast-export` or your shell is misconfigured to not behave in a proper POSIX manner.

Comment: I ran it again into the empty repo, and I can clearly see all the data in the `object` folder is missing and also `pull-requests` under `refs` and also some folders under `stash-refs/pull-requests`. so how can I tell if it really works and which data I lost?

Comment: Assuming your destination repository isn't bare, you can check out a branch using something like `git checkout master`.  You can also use `git log` to see your branches.  All refs are packed by default so you won't see anything in the refs directory.